# How to modify the behaviour of Tire filters so they match more than one word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have an `Item` model that belongs to a `Product` model. I want to filter `Items` using `product.platform`. I setup a delegate method `item.product_platform` and have indexed its output.

It appears that Tire/ES filters by one word, and in lowercase, only. So:

```
item.product_platform = "Nintendo Wii"
filter :term, product_platform: "wii"          # works
filter :term, product_platform: "nintendo"     # works
filter :term, product_platform: "Wii"          # does not work
filter :term, product_platform: "Nintendo"     # does not work
filter :term, product_platform: "nintendo wii" # does not work
filter :term, product_platform: "Nintendo Wii" # does not work
```

But I would like it to return a result when I pass in a precise string, like "Nintendo Wii".

Here's my `item.rb`

```
  belongs_to :product
  delegate :platform, to: :product, prefix: true

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search do
      query { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?

      filter :term, product_platform: params[:platform] if params[:platform]
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(include: :product, methods: :product_platform)
  end
```

Here are my mappings:

```
  mapping date_detection: false do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :user_id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :product_id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :product_platform
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to the fact that elasticsearch analyzes and tokenizes all the stuff that you put in the index unless you configure it otherwise.

depending on what you WANT to filter on, you have several options:

1. using `:index => 'not_analyzed'`
2. using `:analyzer => 'keyword'`

have a look at this question and the liked github issues: [using elasticsearch to filter through tags with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822019/using-elasticsearch-to-filter-through-tags-with-whitespace)